# Are there any zeta functions with concurrent derivative shifts in multiple variables?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, zeta-functions, taylor-series, classification

Expressions for rational zeta series have been obtained by considering the Taylor series of zeta functions. For instance, one has \begin{align}\zeta(s,x+y) &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{y^{k}}{k!} \frac{\partial^{k}}{\partial x^{k}} \zeta(s,x) \\ &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{s+k-1}{s-1} (-y)^{k} \zeta(s+k,x). \qquad \qquad(1) \end{align}
The Taylor series has a nice expression involving binomial sums thanks to the (derivative) [shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheffer_sequence) property of the Hurwitz zeta function $\zeta(s,q)$ in $s$: $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial q} \zeta(s,q) = -s \zeta(s+1,q). \qquad \qquad (2)$$

We could generalize this result by means of the [Barnes](http://youngp.people.cofc.edu/hurwitz.pdf) multiple zeta function, which is defined as $$\zeta_{r}(w_{1}, \dots, w_{r},s,a) := \sum_{t_{1}=0}^{\infty} \dots \sum_{t_{r}=0}^{\infty} (a + w_{1}t_{1} + \dots + w_{r}t_{r})^{-s}  . \qquad \qquad (3)$$

In this case, we obtain: $$\frac{\partial}{\partial a} \zeta_{r}(w_{1}, \dots, w_{r}, s, a) = -s \zeta_{r}(w_{1}, \dots, w_{r}, s+1,a). \qquad \qquad (4) $$
Please note that this is a generalization of $(2)$, because $\zeta_{1}(1,0, \dots,0, s,a) = \zeta(s,a). $

However, it is still “only” a derivative shift in one variable. What I'm looking for is a derivative shift of a zeta function -- say, $\zeta^{*}(\cdot)$ -- in multiple variables at once. It would look something like this (Equation $(5)$): $$ \boxed{ \frac{\partial}{\partial p} \zeta^{*}(s_{1}, \dots, s_{m},p) = f(s_{1}, \dots, s_{m}) \zeta^{*}(s_{1} + k_{1}, s_{2} + k_{2}, \dots, s_{m} + k_{m}, p)  }  $$ for some polynomial $f(s_{1}, \dots, s_{m}) \in \mathbb{Q}[s_{1}, \dots, s_{m}]$ and some $k_{1}, \cdots, k_{m} \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I've tried finding such a $\zeta^{*}(\cdot)$ by considering several modified/generalised zeta functions, but so far I haven't found any that obey property $(5)$. Here are some counterexamples.

*Counterexample 1*:
Let $$ \zeta_{2}(s,s;a) := \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+1+a)^{s}} \sum_{m=0}^{n}\frac{1}{(m+a)^{s}} . \qquad \qquad (6)$$ This is a generalization of the Multiple Zeta [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_zeta_function) where we set $s_{1} = s_{2} = s$. Then:

\begin{align} \frac{\partial}{\partial a} \zeta_{2}(s,s;a) &= -s(\zeta_{2}(s+1,s;a) + \zeta_{2}(s,s+1;a) ) . \qquad \qquad (7) \\
&\neq f_{1}(s) \zeta_{2}(s+k_{1}, s+k_{2} ; a). \qquad \qquad (8)
\end{align}
for some $f_{1}(s) \in \mathbb{Q}[s]$ and $k_{1}, k_{2} \in \mathbb{Z}$.

*Counterexample 2*: Let $$T(s,s,s,v) := \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (m+v)^{-s}(n+v)^{-s}(m+n+v)^{-s}. \qquad \qquad (9) $$
This function is a generalization of the [Mordell-Tornheim](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0505647) double zeta function with $a=b=c=s$. Then $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial v} T(s,s,s,v) = -s [T(s+1,s,s,v) + T(s,s+1,s,v) + T(s,s,s+1,v) ]. \qquad (10) $$
Even when we allow $v=0$, I was only able to reduce $(10)$ to $$-s[T(s+1,s+1,s-1,0) + T(s,s,s+1,0)], \qquad \qquad (11)$$ not any further.

> **Question**: are there any zeta functions that satisfy the “derivative shift” property $(5)$ when $m>1$?